# JavascriptExecutor SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier. Why?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, browser-automation, javascript-injection

Java

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Boolean ready = (Boolean)js.executeScript("the below JavaScript");
```

JavaScript

```
var ready = false;
window.onload = function() {
    ready = true;
}
window.sleep = function() {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000));
}
for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    if(ready) {
           return true;
    }
    await sleep();
 }
 return false;
```

UPDATE: *Sorry about the previous syntax error "funtion" in my post. That was a typo not in my actual code. All syntax errors should be gone, but I still get "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier".*

What this code is trying to do is wait for a maximum amount of time for the page to be loaded. I typically return document.readyState to check for that condition but in unique circumstances Chrome will suddenly stop loading the page and document.readyState hangs for 5+ minutes. This is killing my code so I am attempting to develop single-threaded code to kind of mimic a typically multi-threaded process.

Since JavaScript is single threaded (such a disappointing feature for a cool language like JavaScript), we have to be creative.

This code works in the browser console if you replace `return true;` with `console.log('true');` and `return false;` with `console.log('false');` so I don't see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed there are some mistakes in your JavaScript code.

The first mistake is, in third line
`window.sleep = funtion() { return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 2000)); }`, the `function` spelling is wrong.

The second mistake is you should not use `await` when there is no `async` in your function definition. Here is the thing, `async` ensures that the function returns a promise, and wraps non-promises in it. The keyword `await` makes JavaScript wait until that promise settles and returns its result. `await` works **only inside** `async` functions. So you can avoid using these completely or you need to format it accordingly.

The third mistake is, you are trying to do `return true;` from the for loop of the if condition which is not allowed basically because it is not wrapped inside the function.

The fourth mistake is, you are not calling the `window.onload` function - as the result, it is always returns false even though the page is loaded.

The fifth thing is, I don't know what incomplete `resolve` is doing in `window.sleep` function.

The sixth thing is, you are returning `return false;` at the end without any reference which is completely meaningless.

I have modified the code and avoided the above mistakes, please look into it.

Below is the modified JavaScript code:

```
var status = false;
window.sleep = function() { 
    return setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("=> Waited for 2 seconds...");
    }, 2000);
}
var getStatus = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        if(window.onload = function() {
            return true;
            }) {
            status = true;
            console.log(i+"). Loaded ? "+status);
            break;
        } else {
            console.log(i+"). Loaded ? "+status);
            sleep();
        }
    }
    return status;
}
getStatus();
```

Try the below Java code which prints `true` after the page loads :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\NotBackedUp\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Boolean result = (Boolean) js.executeScript("var status = false;\r\n" + 
        "window.sleep = function() { \r\n" + 
        "   return setTimeout(() => {\r\n" + 
        "       console.log(\"=> Waited for 2 seconds...\");\r\n" + 
        "   }, 2000);\r\n" + 
        "}\r\n" + 
        "var getStatus = function() {\r\n" + 
        "   for(var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {\r\n" + 
        "       if(window.onload = function() {\r\n" + 
        "           return true;\r\n" + 
        "           }) {\r\n" + 
        "           status = true;\r\n" + 
        "           console.log(i+\"). Loaded ? \"+status);\r\n" + 
        "           break;\r\n" + 
        "       } else {\r\n" + 
        "           console.log(i+\"). Loaded ? \"+status);\r\n" + 
        "           sleep();\r\n" + 
        "       }\r\n" + 
        "   }\r\n" + 
        "   return status;\r\n" + 
        "}\r\n" + 
        "return getStatus();");
System.out.println(result);
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Thanks for the help with the typo. That wasn't it though. I think your logic is a little different than what I was going for. I simplified my post to be easier to read. It was kind of a mess. Are you saying I need to call `executeAsyncScript()`? I'll have to give that a go in the morning. Unless you're talking about the `sleep()` method. In that case `sleep()` would be asynchronous because of the promise in the function so you would use `await sleep()`.

Comment: I think you are getting `SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function` error not the one that you have mentioned above, can you check once again?

Comment: I'm not saying that you need to call `executeAsyncScript()` but you need to include `async` for the promise function corresponding to `await`

Comment: Can you share the stack trace if possible so that it will be easy to trace the cause